# how to reply message to the sender client with actioncable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

in socket.io, you can reply message to sender like:

```
 socket.on('records', function(sheet_id){
    records = Record.all
    //send message to sender
    socket.emit('records', records);
  });
```

but in rails:

```
 class BoardChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
   def subscribed
     stream_from "board:#{params[:board]}"
   end

   def speak
     # client will call @perform('speak')
     result = do_something()
     # how to send 'result' to sender?
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [ActionCable::Connection::Base#transmit](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/lib/action_cable/connection/base.rb#L94) method

```
class BoardChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "board:#{params[:board]}"
  end

  def speak
    result = do_something()
    transmit(result) # send message to current connection (sender)
  end
end
```

Comment: can you help me with another question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892367/how-to-send-message-to-all-client-except-sender-in-rails-actioncable