# how to send message to all client except sender in rails/actioncable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, actioncable

in socket.io, you can send message to all client except sender like:

```
socket.broadcast.emit('user connected');
```

but in rails/actioncable, how to do that?

```
class BoardChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
   def subscribed
     stream_from "board:#{params[:board]}"
   end

   def speak
     # client will call @perform('speak')
     result = do_something()
     # how to send 'result' to all client except sender?
   end
 end
```

Comment: On [plezi.io](http://www.plezi.io) you can do this using the [`#broadcast` method](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/plezi/Plezi/Controller#broadcast-instance_method) I assume Rails would have something similar, probably called `publish`... but I'm not sure.

Comment: Same case here. Managed a workaround in the frontend but I don't like the solution. Every example out there (including documentation) assumes the sender should receive the event he sent. The other workaround in the backend is to pass along sender socket id, pull clients, remove sender and then broadcast manually to each client using a loop.

Comment: Have you tried using a different broadcast name for each individual user? Something like `stream_from "board:#{params[:board]}:#{user.id}"`. Then each user gets their own stream, which you can broadcast with a loop to only the specific users whom should receive it.

Comment: no solution since?

Answer (score 3):

I have been worrying about this problem all afternoon. All ready to give up, just lying in bed, my mind flashed a solution it works! ! ! Sign in to share

```
 class BoardChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
   def subscribed
     stream_from "board:#{params[:board]}"
     stream_from "global_stream"
   end
 end
```

Then, when you want to broadcast all users, you can:

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast "global_stream", "some messages"
```

Of course, you can also broadcast to special users. you can:

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast "board:#{params[:board]}", "some messages"
```

Perfect!!!

Answer (score 1):

Using jobs, you can make this with the logic in a partial.
In your model after create a record, call the job perform passing the self record. 
See bellow how pass message to recieved data(at channel) using broadcast.

```
   ...  

   def perform(message)
     ActionCable.server.broadcast "board:#{params[:board]}",
     message: render_message(message)
   end

   private

   def 
     ApplicationController.renderer.render(
       partial: 'messages/message.html.erb',
       locals: { message: message }
     )
   end
```

Create a partial in views/messages/_message.html.erb and in your code make

```
 <%= if message.sender_id == current_user.id %>
   The code to report that forwarded message.
 <%= else %>
   The code to send the message to all except sender.
 <% end %>
```